# Antlr4 lexer rule with action gets rather slow processing long strings

Tags: antlr4, lexer

I work with a lexer grammar for a language that has binary strings formatted like this octetstring:

'00A1C2'O

The rule for these strings contain the following (simplified for clarity):

```
boolean isOdd = false;

...
(
   [0-9a-fA-F] { isOdd = !isOdd; }
   ...
)*
```

This g4 file has been written long ago and works correctly functionally, but I have found accidentally that the above part of the grammar gets rather slow when processing binary strings that contain thousands of characters. If I remove the action part, there is no slowdown.

Tested this with multiple antlr version and found no real difference.

I have refactored the grammar and now it performs well, but I'm curious if this slowdown is normal or not. Having a very limited knowledge of antlr internals, my guess is that calling an action for a rule is an expensive operation and doing this couple of thousand times can degrade performance.

Anyway, I am still curious about the reason for this regression, so I would be grateful if someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of embedded code inside `( … )*`<sup>†</sup>, then it is not odd things are getting slow. Preferably, you don’t even use target specific code inside your grammar. Quite often, it is a far better option to leave out the code from parser- of lexer rules and perform certain validations after the input was parsed. You'd do such things in a visitor or listener: it will make parsing/lexing faster and will keep you grammar clean of embedded target code.

<sup>†</sup> which, as mentioned by Mike in the comments, can get executed thousands of times because the `*` means zero or more times

Comment: Especially when you consider that the target code is executed for *every* letter that is collected as part of the rule. So it runs thousands of times in such a scenario.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my point, but I neglected to mention it explicitly. Edited it in my answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Actually this grammar is old and I am relatively new to this project; the historical decision was not to use the antlr parse tree and visitors but to build the AST directly from the parser (to save memory). Furthermore, a few checks are performed as lexer actions. I have already moved out these checks from the lexer, but unfortunately refactoring the parser is a no go due to the complexity of the project.